# restoring previous value of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL2008 R2.

An update on a field was made without a rollback, I need to rollback this field but have no previous value.

I am trying to restore the previous value of a field on a set of data in a table.  Is it possible to view the previous value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how big your database is ?? you can restore you database using STOPAT clause.

Comment: @Craid - You may want to ask on a DBA forum as well.   http://dba.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that. Only if you have a backup of the database just before the change. Restoring that backup, however, would also bring back all other data to that state.

What you *could* do is create a new database from the last backup before the change. You could then find the value and change the real database. The new database can then be removed.

Comment: I don't recall the details, but you can also take the last backup and roll-forward through the transaction log to a specific point.  Assuming the transaction logging is appropriately configured.

Answer (score 0):

Without some third party solution or fn_dblog command you can't do too much. You can also take a look at answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20575261/2808398

Also please take a look on post regarding the fn_dblog command https://stackoverflow.com/a/9018249/2808398